# Stop propagation of 'click' event in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In one of our projects we're using `Leaflet` along with `Leaflet.markercluster` plugin. Looking through the `Leaflet`'s sources I found that it appends `_collapse()` function to the map's `click` event, so whenever I click on the map it contracts previously expanded cluster.
Now, I want to disable this behavior. If the cluster is expanded, then I just want to deselect all of its markers on `click` event (and don't contract the cluster itself). Here is the piece of my code:

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    scope.deselectAllMarkers();
});
```

I tried to add the following lines in the end of this one-line callback in order to stop propagation of `click` event:

`scope.L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);`
`scope.L.DomEvent.preventDefault(e);`
`scope.L.DomEvent.stop(e);`
`scope.L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e.originalEvent);`
`scope.L.DomEvent.preventDefault(e.originalEvent);`
`scope.L.DomEvent.stop(e.originalEvent);`

And none of them works. Default listener which is hidden inside of the `Leaflet` sources keeps its invocation whenever I click on the map. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I've solved the issue by manual removal of default `click` handler which was invoking the `_collapse()` method, as far as I remember. Dirty, but it did the trick.

Answer (score 31):

I know that this answer is quite late, but if someone is interested in a solution, here is how i have solved it.

This snippet here below is an example of binding a function to the `click` event.

```
map.on('click', doSomething);
```

Actually, after checking [leaflet's API](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-objects) and some geekish debugging, it seems that the event returns an object, not the event itself. The event itself is wrapped into a field within the returned object.

```
var doSomething = function(map) {
    // stop propagation
    map.originalEvent.preventDefault();
};
```

When using the above snippet, the event bubbling has stopped, something which i wanted, and probably what you wanted.

Comment: There is no `originalEvent` on a click event (anymore?).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Are you sure? I just checked leaflet's documentation and [it is still present](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#mouseevent-originalevent)? Best to check the object to see if it is a `MouseEvent` object (and thus not something else)

Comment: Hum, interesting, I never saw this guy while debugging events generated by leaflet. Perhaps a way of finding which ones are generated events and which ones are user events!

Comment: Note that this only prevents the event from propagating "to the page", but it will still trigger other click handlers on the map itself, which you can prevent by setting `bubblingMouseEvents: false` on whatever thing or layer you want exclusive clicking rights on.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this answer is event more quite late, but as in jquery you can use `.off`

```
map.on('click', doSomething);
map.off('click');
```

It works fine for any leaflet events.

I use it for `'zoomend'` event to be triggered one time only.

```
map.on('moveend', function(e){
    console.log("any code");
    map.off('moveend');
});
```

Comment: This is the only way which worked for me to catch the click event in a KML layer (the L.KML library to load it, L.featureGroup to catch the click event) but ignore it on "map" (L.Map). I wanted to catch click events on "map" only when clicked outside the KML layer (like in Google Maps).

The only problem in the solution above is the later clicks are ignored, because the event handler is removed forever. You have to recreate it - delayed e.g. via setTimeout(function () { recreate the original event handler for map.on("click") }, 1). If you recreate it immediatelly, it gets called, too.

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me...

```
var div = L.DomUtil.get('div_id');
if (!L.Browser.touch) {
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(div);
    L.DomEvent.on(div, 'mousewheel', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
} else {
    L.DomEvent.on(div, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
}
```

Thanks to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104507/disable-panning-dragging-on-leaflet-map-for-div-within-map

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the event propagation from an event handler. You need to use the builtin Leaflet helper after the page has loaded, like this:

```
$('.element').each (i,el)->

  L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(el);
```

Answer (score -3):

You have use like this [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
map.on('click', function(e) {  //don't forget to pass this 'e' event parameter
    e.preventDefault();
    scope.deselectAllMarkers();        
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;     
});
```

Try anyone of this

1.`event.stopPropagation()`
 2.`event.preventDefault()`
 3.[**`return false`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/1671639)

Comment: I tried all of them - no luck. `L.DomEvent.preventDefault(e)` and `L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e)` invoke `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` respectively.

Comment: Did you try your own answer ?

Comment: map.on('click' does not pass the standard event object