# Different actions for clicking on Leaflet layer vs map

Tags: leaflet

I've got a click event for the main part of my leaflet map. But if the user clicks on a specific layer I want to do something else and *not* the other action. I thought I could stop the propagation of the map click using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22451817/186212)

> map.originalEvent.preventDefault()

But I still get both events.

Here's a cutting from my code

```
    this.map.on('click', (event) => {
        console.log('map clicked')
    })


    this.boundaryLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(this.map);
    this.boundaryLayer.on('click', (event) => {
        console.log('boundary clicked', event);
        event.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code stops the map's click event from being fired

```
    this.boundaryLayer.on('click', (event) => {
            console.log('boundary clicked', event);
            L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(event);
    });
```